# Spring with cassandra

Tags: spring, spring-data, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-rest, spring-data-cassandra

How to integrate the spring with cassandra and how to use with multiple table.Please explain with example.

I read about easycassandra

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (We're not here to do all the work - you need to have at least attempted to solve this yourself after reading the relevant documentation.)

Comment: I read and implement the simple java file to do this but i can't find anything that can help me in spring data cassandra

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data Cassandra was Released this week and it does everything you need. It is the official Spring and Cassandra integration module.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/

Comment: Please note: The link above works, but the https version of it does not pull in much of the page. Not sure what is going on with it. This could be a problem for people using extenstions that auto-https everything  https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/